# table within footnote

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have been looking for this for long, but I could find nothing. I have been experience problems when I want to embed a `table` within `\footnote`. I don't seem to be able to compile something simple like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Bla\footnote{bla bla: 

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l c | c | c }
bla & blu & bli & blo \\
c & i & a & o \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Bla}
\end{table}                                                                                     


bla         }

\end{document}
```

Notice that the `\footnotemark` - `\footnotetext` solution does not help at all. Has someone ever struggled with this?

Comment: Please explain the use case for placing an entire table in a footnote. My first reaction is that it's very ill-advised to do so. However, I may be missing something.

Comment: I do not see why, honestly. It is just to put additional data on footnote, and remove some clutter from the body.

Comment: I might understand setting a table in a footnote, but definitely not a captioned one.

Comment: Oh yeah - that is true. I don't really need the caption. The problem was there even when removing the caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this.  You can't put a floating `table` inside a `\footnote`.  Put you can use `\captionof` inside there (`caption` package) to caption a non-floating `tabular`.

EDITED to reduce caption font size to `\footnotesize` inside the footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%\textheight 2in
\begin{document}

Bla\footnote{%
\renewcommand\captionfont{\footnotesize}%
bla bla: 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l c | c | c }
bla & blu & bli & blo \\
c & i & a & o \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\captionof{table}{Bla}


bla         }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great! thank you! How can I modify the size of the caption? I tried to use `\footnotesize` inside the enviroment of `\captionof{table}`, but "Table X" does not get shrunk.

Comment: @RobertP. Inside the footnote, `\renewcommand\captionfont{\footnotesize}`

Comment: You definitively cannot use the `table` environment inside a footnote. `table` is a floating object which uses the _insertion_ mecanism of TeX. Since `\footnote` is also an insertion, you are using an insertion inside an insertion, which is impossible.

Comment: @EricDomenjoud But I am *not* using the `table` environment at all, and say so at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Oops. My comment was for Robert.

Comment: No problem.  But for future reference, the way to direct a comment at a particular person in the discussion is to use the @ sign before their name, as in @EricDomenjoud.  Then, you will get a notification of my comment, and anyone reading it will know at whom the comment was directed.